# Is there a solution like Apache ActiveMQ on top of HDFS?

Tags: stack, storage, distributed, hdfs, web-crawler

I want to store webpages fetched by a web crawler. I don't have any random access. so whenever i want to read the stored data, i read from the start to the end.

We have tried solutions like HBase but one of the most good things about HBase is random access to records which we don't need at all. HBase has not proved to be stable for us after 1.5 years of test.

I want just a stack or queue on top of HDFS becuase the number of webpages is about 1 billion. I don't even want the queue behaviour of ActiveMQ i just want to be able to store the webpages so that i can read them all in case of a failure.

I don't want to use Files because i don't want to handle things like file rotations, file consistencies and ...

It is worth to mention that we need HDFS so we can run MapReduce jobs on the data when we want to send all the stored data to a solr cluster and to have good things like redundancy and availability by HDFS.

Is there a service on HDFS that just stores JMS records without any functionality for random access and without transparent view of records?

Comment: Are per-record updates required, since you mention you dislike the use of collected or individual files? If so, that is a random access pattern and Apache HBase would be the only good scalable way to go. Perhaps we could help you with stability issues if you could point us at specifics.

Comment: Per-record updates are done on our Meta cluster which we'll certainly use HBase. We just need a storage for our Fetched Pages (Serializable Objects) which we only use when the index fails and we have to send all the data from the beginning of the time to current time.

Comment: About the stability, we have seen that ActiveMQ is much more stable than HBase, Of course it is because it doesn't have the valuable functionalities that HBase has (In our case we don't need that functionality). For example putting Nutch WebPage objects into a cluster of 9 HBase Nodes is much slower than a single ActiveMQ machine.